# Why is Java evaluating the wrong side of ternary operation?

Tags: java, conditional-operator

I might miss some simple explanation, but the following line throws a `NullPointerException`:

```
Long sum = true 
           ? 
           fiscalDocumentUtil.getFullValue(fiscalDocument.getInvoice()) 
           :
           (long) fiscalDocument.getReceipt().getAmount();
```

While

```
Long sum = true 
           ? 
           fiscalDocumentUtil.getFullValue(fiscalDocument.getInvoice()) 
           :
           null
```

does not. I would also like to mention that

```
fiscalDocumentUtil.getFullValue(fiscalDocument.getInvoice())
```

does not throw an exception on its own, while

```
(long) fiscalDocument.getReceipt().getAmount()
```

does.

Is the second side evaluated? Or am I butchering something?

EDIT

Some additional info, asked in the comments:
`fiscalDocumentUtil.getFullValue(fiscalDocument.getInvoice())` returns null.
The return type of `fiscalDocumentUtil.getFullValue(fiscalDocument.getInvoice())` is Long.

The return type of `fiscalDocument.getReceipt().getAmount()` is `Integer`.

If I emit the explicit (long) conversion, the behavior is the same.

Edit 2

A minimal reproducible example: `Long val =true ? (Long) null: Integer.valueOf(1);`. This was partially suggested by the answer of MC Emperor and partially suggested by comments. Of course, this example already somewhat answers the question, since the second expression does not need to throw an exception, as it turns out.

Comment: Does `fiscalDocumentUtil.getFullValue(fiscalDocument.getInvoice())` *return* `null`?

Comment: It's likely either a case of `(long) null` or `null.someMethod()`. Check the returns of `#getReceipt`, `#getAmount`, and any other method dereferencing a value (aka `value.dereferencing()`, the period) for a value of `null`, which you cannot call methods on.

Comment: @Rogue I think he understands that, what he's asking is : true ? shouldBeExecuted() : shouldNotBeExecuted(); while it's the shouldNotBeExecuted() that throws the NPE

Comment: Could you provide the signature of the methods? I suspect it's NPE is related to the Java unboxing, If you return Long and then you use it as 'long' (primitive), when Long is null than it throws NPE.

Comment: @Stultuske similarly, it can still be a problem of `(long) null`, and that can be _caused_ by the fact that it is a ternary expression (and less likely to be caught with the first `#getFullValue` alone). Per JLS [§15.25.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se9/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2), the entire ternary expression is evaluated to `long`: `If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.`

Comment: Whatever is going on here is not caused by evaluating the wrong side of the ternary.  It will be happening in the right side.  Somehow.

Comment: @StephenC by "right side", do you mean right (not left), or right (not wrong)?

Comment: If the exception is in that code, the 3 possibilities are: `fiscalDocumentUtil` is `null`, `fiscalDocument` is `null`, or `fiscalDocument.getInvoice()` is returning `null` which is being unboxed for some reason.  But it is not clear from the information provided why it *needs* to unbox something here.

Comment: I mean right as in not wrong.  (Read my 2nd sentence in the context of my 1st one ....)

Comment: But my take on this is that we need a proper [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if we are going to give a definitive answer.  There is too much "missing information".

Comment: @Rogue not if you take into account the other remarks in the question, that the part that should be executed on it's own doesn't throw the exception if you change the other part

Comment: Never ever go "code does this or that". Give us a [mcve] please.

Comment: @Stultuske It's still a possibility (and I'm in the MRE camp too). In `a ? b : c`, if `b` is `null`, then `Long ex = b;` is valid. But if `Long ex = true ? null : (long) c`, then null will be boxed to `long`, hence the NPE.

Comment: @Rogue if a ? b : c with a = true throws an NPE because b = null, then a ? b : null with a being true should throw an NPE as well, according to the question, that is not the case

Comment: @Stultuske that'd only occur if you put a literal null there, this is a null from a function call. See here: https://ideone.com/JT3QYo , you get an NPE.

Comment: @Rogue I've given the exact example as is stated in the question. That's the point.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If `foo` has type `Long` and `bar` has type `long`, then `true ? foo : bar` has type `long`, and is equivalent to `true ? foo.longValue() : bar`. As the *Java Language Specification* [puts it](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se15/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25.2):

> If one of the second and third operands is of primitive type T, and the type of the other is the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T, then the type of the conditional expression is T.

(In your case, `T` is `long`, and "the result of applying boxing conversion (§5.1.7) to T" is `Long`.)

The fact that you try to put the result in a `Long` variable doesn't change that fact; it just gives you the equivalent of `Long.valueOf(true ? foo.longValue() : bar)`, with unboxing followed by boxing.

In your case, `foo == null`, so the unboxing throws a NullPointerException, so the boxing never happens.

Comment: Per the question, `foo` is not null, and `true ? foo : null` does *not* throw an NPE.

Comment: @ernest_k: Re: "Per the question, `foo` is not null": The question does not make that claim; you must have misread it. Re: "`true ? foo : null` does *not* throw an NPE": Correct, but I'm not sure why you bring that up, since nothing in this answer suggests that it *would*?

Comment: @ernest_k - We don't know it is not `null`.  We know that the OP says it is not `null`.  Not the same thing.

Comment: @StephenC: Re: "We know that the OP says it is not `null`": Am I going blind? I really don't see anywhere that the OP makes that claim, but you and ernest_k both seem confident that (s)he does . . .

Comment: Well, you're both right about my wrong assumption/understanding that "`foo` is not null", thanks. So I suppose the OP only has to confirm that `fiscalDocumentUtil.getFullValue(fiscalDocument.getInvoice()) ` is `Long`-typed, and that it's returning null

Comment: Ok, the same happens if I don't make the explicit (long) conversion. The left side returns Long and the right side returns Integer. Does this cover that too?

Comment: Maybe, maybe not.  There are too many statements that have been made without clear evidence.  (Just 'cos you think something is happening doesn't necessarily mean that it actually is.) We can only give you a definitive answer if you provide a proper minimal reproducible example.  (Without the full evidence, people make assumptions ... which may be wrong.)

Comment: @maybesomename: When the right side has type `Integer` instead of `long`, the overall picture is the same -- the left side still gets autounboxed and then boxed -- but it falls under a different clause of that JLS section.

Comment: @maybesomename if one of the branches returns `Integer`, the code would surely *not* compile, neither implicit nor explicit casting to `Long` would be possible.

Comment: @ernest_k it most certainly does compile.

Comment: @maybesomename you should then provide a *complete* and reproducible example, as Stephen C has been saying. We're probably losing one another in confusions between `int`/`Integer`, `long`/`Long`, and this isn't going to go anywhere.

Comment: @ernest_k: When both branches are numeric wrapper types (in this case Long and Integer), the whole thing is treated as a numeric conditional expression, not a reference conditional expression, so the selected branch gets unboxed and then (if necessary) the final result gets reboxed. So while you're right that you can't convert directly from Integer to Long, conditional expressions provide a non-obvious way to implicitly convert from Integer to int to long to Long!

Comment: @ernest_k: Check out https://ideone.com/etz2fc.

Comment: @ernest_k: the simple line `Long val =true ? Long.valueOf(1): Integer.valueOf(1);` also compiles.

Comment: @maybesomename but the simple line Long val =true ? null: Integer.valueOf(1); does not.

Comment: @juwil: True, but I don't see how that's relevant. Care to elaborate?

Answer (score 1):

Well, Java only evaluates the left expression, as the condition is `true`.

You said that `fiscalDocumentUtil.getFullValue(fiscalDocument.getInvoice())` in itself does not throw an NullPointerException.

The only thing I can think of, is that `fiscalDocumentUtil.getFullValue(fiscalDocument.getInvoice())` *returns* `null`. Reproducible with:

```java
Long sum = true ? null : (long) 23L;
```

Because one of the operands is a primitive, the other one is *subject to boxing conversion*, in this case, unboxed to `long`.